# doing two mysql requests in one

Tags: mysql, select

I have this two working queries:

```
select distinct(foo) from my_table;

+--------------------------------------------------+
| foo                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| bar1                                             |
| bar2                                             |
| ...                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

And:

```
select   foo, sum(position)/count(position) as average_position
from     (select   foo, position
          from     my_table
          where    foo = 'bar1'
          order by date desc limit 3) as subquery
group by foo;

+------------------+------------------+
| foo              | average_position |
+------------------+------------------+
| bar1             |           8.3333 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

And now I would like to do this in one request, so I want to do my second request for each distinct `foo` in one request.

OUTPUT must be:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| foo              | average_position |
+------------------+------------------+
| bar1             |           8.3333 |
| bar2             |           7.0000 |
| ...              |           ...... |
+------------------+------------------+
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Unclear.  What is the significance of "3"?

Comment: it is just a limit i want to set. do the average only on the X latest row ordered by date

Comment: See my [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) for the most efficient way to do such.

Comment: i looked at your link but can't figure out to adapt it, i am not a sql guru, can you give me an example to work for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many values you have for the 'foo' column, you may be able to accomplish this with a union:

```
select   foo, sum(position)/count(position) as average_position
from     (
    select   foo, position
    from     my_table
    where    foo = 'bar1'
    order by date desc limit 3
union all
    select   foo, position
    from     my_table
    where    foo = 'bar2'
    order by date desc limit 3
) as subquery
group by foo;
```

Comment: For now i have more than 6000 differents "foo", so i can't write a subquery for each one of them